# If query is empty return "no data"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google Sheets and my database looks like this:

[image]

I have a query formula that changes dynamically based on the month:

[image]

my query:

```
=QUERY('database',"SELECT B,C WHERE A = '"&A1&"'")
```

At the beginning of the months I don't have data, so I want to display something like this:
[image]

I want the column `userID` permanent in all month, but the column `name` to display "NO DATA"

I already tried with `IFNA` or `IFERROR` but that won't work, because if there's no data, the query is still successful because it displays the column names.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this longer combination of several formulas:

```
=arrayformula(
     query({A2:C;split(E1&"_"&unique(filter(B2:B,B2:B<>""))&"_NO DATA", "_")},
     "select Col2, max(Col3) where Col1 = '"&E1&"' 
                             group by Col2 
                             order by Col2 label max(Col3) ''", 0)
)
```

#### Where:

- A2:C is the dictionary
- B2:B is the column of userIDs
- E1 is the Month

#### Outputs:

[image: output]
[image: output1]
[image: output3]
[image: output2]

Comment: thanks for the solution, for some reason I get this error `In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.`

Comment: my modified formula
=arrayformula(
     query({Data!$A$2:$C;split(G3&"_"&unique(filter(Data!$C$2:$C300,Data!$C$2:$C300<>""))&"_NO DATA", "_")},
     "select Col2, max(Col3) where Col1 = '"&G3&"' 
                             group by Col2 
                             order by Col2 label max(Col3) ''", 0)
)

Comment: Hi @DavidSalomon, in your case, you missed out 2 things. First, you are missing the underscore after `G3` and for split after `_NO DATA`, that's why you are missing values on some rows. Second, you are filtering name, not userID. you should get the unique values of filtered userIDs. Try this: `=arrayformula( query({Data!$A$2:$C;split(G3&"_"&unique(filter(Data!$B$2:$B300,Data!$B$2:$B300<>""))&"_NO DATA", "_")}, "select Col2, max(Col3) where Col1 = '"&G3&"' group by Col2 order by Col2 label max(Col3) ''", 0) )`